# How to convert a date to text format in Excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Excel store date column called Today and data type is date

| Today |
| --- |
| 13/12/2021 |
| 14/12/2021 |
| 15/12/2021 |

When I import the Excel to another Excel using Python, how to change the date type to text type?

Below is my code and try to convert, but not work. Could anyone give me advice? Thanks

```
data.insert(0, {'Date':datetime.strptime(str(Today),'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')})
```

Comment: from datetime import datetime
today = '13/12/2021'
type(datetime.strptime(str(today),'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
<class 'str'>

Comment: Hi @ShekharSamanta , thank you for your advise, but when i open the excel , the column is date type , can i convert the type to text before open excel?thanks

Answer (score 1):

Excel try to recognize date format even if you cast your column `Today` as string.

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [123, 456, 789], 'Name': ['Louis', 'Paul', 'Alexandre'],
                   'Today': pd.date_range('2021-12-14', periods=3, freq='D')})
print(df)

# Output:
    ID       Name      Today
0  123      Louis 2021-12-14
1  456       Paul 2021-12-15
2  789  Alexandre 2021-12-16
```

If you export your dataframe with `df.to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False)`, you got:

[image]

Here, the trick:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('data.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    wb = writer.book
    ws = wb.active
    # For the third column only (Today, Col C)
    for col in ws.iter_cols(min_col=3, max_col=3):
        # For all rows below header (C2, C3, C4, ...)
        for cell in col[1:]:
            cell.number_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

Now, you got:

[image]

Comment: HI @Corralien , thank you for your support! I have used pip install to install openpyxl and use from openpyxl import Workbook but cannot use active and "workbook is not accessed" : show AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active'

Comment: @iamnew. Does it work for you?

Comment: Hi @Corralien , could i ues this way to export excel and convert number format? thanks self.Today.to_excel(self.path+"Today.xlsx", sheet_name = 'Sheet3', index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')

Comment: The engine I used is `openpyxl` not `xlsxwriter`.

Comment: Hi Corralien, worbook active not work ,any advise to convert the date to text? thank so much

Comment: I updated my answer. Use `engine='openpyxl'` in `pd.ExcelWriter` to ensure to choose the right engine if both are installed. To install `openpyxl`, `pip install openpyxl` or `conda install openpyxl`.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: no.. show AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'active